# Executing a program on a cd. Couldn't find in search

Tags: ubuntu, data-cd

New to Linux, studying for Linux+.

The textbook comes with a cd for additional exam review and so as expected, I mount the cd (googling as I do so) and I see individual files including a start.exe. I double click it but I get this error:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Error: /media/[user]/9780789754554/start.exe: Can not open file as archive

Errors: 1
```

What is the archive manager? How do I just "run the cd" like I would on Windows? Every google search tells me that the cd should be on /media/cdrom and that I should make the folder if it does not exist. Is this something that I have to do as well for the .exe to run, or is it okay for my cd-roms to be found in /media/[user] and I'm just missing a step?

There's a lot to learn and I'm willing to put in the time but as of now, none of this is intuitive for me.

Answer (score 0):

`/mnt/cdrom` is one of many standardized locations for an optical drive to be mounted.  `/media/[user]/[id]` is fine if that's the location your distruibution uses.  The problem is that you're trying to run Windows executables in a non-Windows environment.  You might have some luck running them through wine, but I'd imagine, it being supplementary material for a Linux+ course of study, that the material should be natively accessible within Linux.  I'd consult the documentation for a section on using the CD from within Linux rather than from within Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I wrote it off as me not understanding Linux well enough to even run a cd-rom which was pretty discouraging. This makes me feel slightly better about myself.

Answer (score 0):

I see the Ubuntu tag and as far as i know, you didn't need to do anything a lot for mounting; the CD would appear on the sidebar and also on  autoplay(Ubuntu has them).
Even then, as @DopeGhoti said either use wine [Official Wine Download page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

or look for some kind of script file ( ending in a ".sh" ). Most probably your disk contains a separate directory for linux. There also will be a file "README" that will greatly help you.

That or you could simply use a computer with windows.